# CLRProfiler disagrees with GC.GetTotalMemory on how much memory I am using

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm working on tracking down a memory leak in my C# app.

My first way of going about this was to start a background worker which prints out the result of `GC.GetTotalMemory()` every 10 seconds to the console.

My leak takes some time to appear, so next I downloaded CLR Profiler. After the console showed I was constantly up around 30-40 MB, I hit "Show heap now". Here's the result (973 kB):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/AD8PmFJ.png]

Both of these work with managed code right? So why do they appear to disagree (significantly) about how much memory my app is using?